# How to prevent maxima to rewrite the output of 2*sqrt(2) to 2^(3/2)?

Tags: output, tex, maxima, simplification

Maxima input of

```
2*sqrt(2)
```

by default returns the output

```
2^(3/2)
```

How can I get Maxima to just return 2*sqrt(2) ?

(I use this in the tex() function.)

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to prevent Maxima from simplifying `2*sqrt(2)` to `2^(3/2)`, with two probably-hard-to-use exceptions:

(1) Turn off simplification entirely. But that disables all simplifications, e.g. `1 + 1` simplifying to `2`. But if you want to try it: just enter `simp : false;`.

(2) Disable the simplification `sqrt(2)` to `2^(1/2)` via `:lisp (setf (get '%sqrt 'operators) nil)` But then Maxima for the most part doesn't know what to do with `sqrt`.

I don't recommend either one of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
simp: false;
tex(2*sqrt(2));
block code...;
simp: true;
```

That way you don't have to disable the simplification permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
(%i1) matchdeclare(n_, integerp,m_, integerp)$
      tellsimp(n_*sqrt(m_), n_*sqrt(box(m_)))$
```

and afterwards:

```
(%i3) 2*sqrt(2);
(%o3) 2 √2

(%i4) sqrt(3)*9;
(%o4) 9 √3
```

You'll notice that the number under the square root sign in the output is colored red, because of box(). But if you select the expression in wxMaxima, and then popup "Copy LaTeX", you'll get exactly what you want, e. g.

```
\[2\,\sqrt{2}\]
```

Unfortunately if you try tex(2*sqrt(2)) to get the TeX code, you'll get `$$2\,\sqrt{\boxed{2}}$$`instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another hack to do that is to use the non-commutative multiplication `.` instead of `*` with `dotconstrules` off:

```
(%i1) texput(".", " ", nary)$

(%i2) 2 . sqrt(2), dotconstrules: false;
(%o2)                             2 . sqrt(2)
(%i3) tex(%)$
$$2 \sqrt{2}$$
```

I think that this solution might be useful, because you can avoid simplification in a part of your expression, while still simplifying as usual in the other part:

```
(%i4) 2 . sqrt(2) * sqrt(4) / 2, dotconstrules: false;
(%o4)                             2 . sqrt(2)
```